# Is it possible to use re2 from Python?

Tags: python, regex, re2

i just discovered http://code.google.com/p/re2, a promising library that uses a long-neglected way ([Thompson NFA](http://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/regexp1.html)) to implement a regular expression engine that can be orders of magnitudes faster than the available engines of awk, Perl, or Python.

so i downloaded the code and did the usual `sudo make install` thing. however, that action had seemingly done little more than adding `/usr/local/include/re2/re2.h` to my system. there seemed to be some `*.a` file in addition, but then what is it with this `*.a` extension?

i would like to use re2 from Python (preferrably Python 3.1) and was excited to see files like `make_unicode_groups.py` in the distro (maybe just used during the build process?). those however were not deployed on my machine.

how can i use re2 from Python?

---

**update** two friendly people have pointed out that i could try to build DLLs / *.so files from the sources and then use Python’s `ctypes` library to access those. can anyone give useful pointers how to do just that? i’m pretty much clueless here, especially with the first part (building the *.so files).

---

**update** i have also posted this question (earlier) to the [re2 developers’ group](http://groups.google.com/group/re2-dev), without reply till now (it is a small group), and today to the (somewhat more populous) [comp.lang.py](http://groups.google.com/group/re2-dev) group [[—thread here—]](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_thread/thread/4c38032f9905efce#). the hope is that people from various corners can contact each other. my guess is a skilled person can do this in a few hours during their 20% your-free-time-belongs-google-too timeslice; it would tie me for weeks. **is there a tool to automatically dumb-down C++ to whatever flavor of C that Python needs to be able to connect?** then maybe getting a viable result can be reduced to clever tool chaining.

*(rant)why is this so difficult? to think that in 2010 we still cannot have our abundant pieces of software just talk to each other. this is such a roadblock that whenever you want to address some C code from Python you must always cruft these linking bits. this requires a lot of work, but only delivers an extension module that is specific to the version of the C code and the version of Python, so it ages fast.(/rant)* **would it be possible to run such things in separate processes (say if i had an re2 executable that can produce results for data that comes in on, say, `subprocess/Popen/communicate()`)?** (this should not be a pure command-line tool that necessitates the opening of a process each time it is needed, but a single processs that runs continuously; maybe there exist wrappers that sort of ‘demonize’ such C code).

Comment: +1 just for the link to the Thompson NFA article

Comment: Checkout the Makefile in the re2 project and modify it build a so file. Then add your own files to the Makefile to provide the interface between re2 and python ctypes. You must used -shared option to build the so files. Just google for Makefile & shared libraries.

Comment: @GregS: google("Glushkov NFA")

Comment: """// By default, the pattern and input text are interpreted as UTF-8.
// The RE2::Latin1 option causes them to be interpreted as Latin-1.""" Looks like legacyware to me :-(

Comment: By the way, AWK uses the Thompson NFA method; GAWK's been doing this for a couple decades. It's only the "modern" languages that have done poorly at this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

David Reiss has put together a Python wrapper for re2.  It doesn't have all of the functionality of Python's re module, but it's a start.  It's available here: http://github.com/facebook/pyre2.

Comment: this is the kind of answer that i have been hoping for. thx a ton!

Comment: Note that the facebook port it very basic and incomplete. You're much better off using one of the forks, like https://github.com/axiak/pyre2

Answer (score 5):

Possible yes, easy no.  Looking at the re2.h, this is a C++ library exposed as a class. There are two ways you could use it from Python.

1.) As Tuomas says, compile it as a DLL/so and use ctypes.  In order to use it from python, though, you would need to wrap the object init and methods into c style externed functions. I've done this in the past with ctypes by externing functions that pass a pointer to the object around.  The "init" function returns a void pointer to the object that gets passed on each subsequent method call.  Very messy indeed.

2.) Wrap it into a true python module. Again those functions exposed to python would need to be extern "C".  One option is to use [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/python/doc/index.html), that would ease this work.

Answer (score 3):

[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) handles C++ (unlike ctypes), so it may be more straightforward to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to build re2 into its own DLL/so and use ctypes to call functions from that DLL/so. You will probably need to define your own entry points in the DLL/so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python package https://pypi.org/project/google-re2/. Although look at the bottom, there are a few requirements to install yourself before installing the python package.